# android app authorisation

Tags: android, authorization

I am making an application in android. How to do role authorisation in android. is there any package. please let me know.

Thanks,
NVN

Answer (score 1):

I never used the Authenticator class. But if you plan to role your own authentication system, its pretty simple. Here are some tips:

- Authenticate over https
- Create a webservice that accepts username and password.
- Once succeeded, save a token or
  something in preferences so the app
  knows it is authenticated.
- I recommend using an oAuth
  implementation because it is the most
  safe. (Don't store email addresses,
  instead use tokens)

Let me know if you need any other help.

**Edit:**

There isn't a library out there does this for you. You have to create a class called Token or User:

```
class Token{
 String token;
 Role role;
 User user;
}
```

Role can be an enum like `enum Role{admin, publisher, writer, reader,...}`.

Then let's say you authenticate against *https://foobar.com/REST/authenticate/?user=foo&password=...*

Which returns a simple JSON or XML (I suggest JSON)

```
{
 token: "12345667",
 role : "publisher",
 user : { userId : "amir", ...}
}
```

So now you make an HTTPS call and authenticate against a user and password. Then parse the json and create a Token object. Store this token object in the app and you should have everything you need.

Comment: Sorry I think I misunderstood your question. Did you mean role authorization or just authorization?

Comment: Actually roles and their permissions are described in the server. A client app on the android device contacts the server by providing username and password for authentication. How can I distinguish the screen based on the role.Can you provide me some suggestions for accomplishing this.

Comment: yes, its helpful. Then on the client side based on the role, I have to provide the options. Please provide me some brief guidelines on how to distinguish the options based on role. is there anything that help to accomplish my tas? Thanks alottt.

Comment: That's a question completely depending on your application. But at some point you will need to do an IF statement to check for permissions before allowing a user do anything secured.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the default Authenticator class? [Here's the API from Google](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Authenticator.html) I hope that helps. =]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to create roles and permissions with this API. I have seen apache shiro. can I use apache shiro for android app.